# How to direct user to a specific page after logging in with Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I redirect a user to a specific page when they login on a particular form I create with Devise? There's this howto page for Devise on [how to redirect to a particular page after sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to%3a-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out). However, I want different forms to sign in to different target pages. Ideally, I can just add another HTML form parameter like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="target" value="/dashboard"/>
```

***UPDATE***: It's important that I maintain the normal functionality of Devise for a login page. That is, if I click on a link that has a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in its controller, then I'll be redirected to a login page. After logging in, then I'm redirected to the original destination page.

Comment: Please can you clarify to me if you are login in with the same model in different forms or with different models?

Comment: @felipeclopes same User model, different forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can simply define the `after_sign_in_path_for` method in your controller like that :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def after_sign_in_path_for
    params[:target] || some_default_url
  end

end
```

And then if your different sign in forms have different targets, then user should be properly redirected

Adding

```
<input type="hidden" name="target" value="/dashboard"/>
```

to each particular form that would redirect to a specific page will then be enough :)

EDIT : I think I finally understood what you exactly want. So here what I would do (based on [this blogpost](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/03/10/rails-redirect-previous-page-after-devise-sign-in/))

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    origin_path = session[:origin_path]
    clear_origin_path
    if origin_path.present?
      origin_path
    else
      params[:target].presence || default_redirect_path
    end
  end

  private

  def authenticate_user!
    store_origin_path
    super
  end

  def store_origin_path
    session[:origin_path] = request.fullpath
  end

  def clear_origin_path
    session[:origin_path] = nil
  end

end
```

So basically, if you try to access a protected path (let's say `/protected_resource`), the path will be stored in the session, and then once user is logged in, the session will be cleared and user correctly redirected

Then if a user goes on one of your different `sign_in` form and if that form contains a `target` input, then user will be redirected to that target.

Finally, if user goes on a form without any target he'll be redirected to a `default_redirect_path` that you might want to customize.

Last thing : I assumed that the redirection to the original request was more important than the target so let's say a user goes on `/protected_resource` and is therefore redirected to a sign_in form, even though this sign_in form has a `target` input, user will be redirected to `/protected_resource` after a successful sign in.

You can easily change that by inverting the conditions in the `after_sign_in_path_for` method

There might be a better way to do that, but this a starting point for you, and you might want to improve it ;)

Let me know if my answer is not detailed enough.

Comment: He wants to know exactly how to make users to "be properly redirected"

Comment: If you explain how to pass extra attributes and handle them in the ApplicationController then the response will be correct.

Comment: well if you put the piece of HTML code he wrote in one of your sign_in form, and then process to sign in, my solution will work. You have everything to make it work, write his html in the view, and my code in your application controller and you're good to go.

Comment: You're tight, sorry, please edit your answer for me to remove the downvote

Comment: What's missing in my post ? If you want to keep the downvote, keep it I don't really care :)

Comment: Just figured out that you showed how to get the parameter, I don't want to keep it!

Comment: how do I make it so if the parameter is not given, the form should have the default Devise behavior? Basically, some links require a login first, so the login page is redirected to. After logging in, then I want the users to go to their intended destination.

Comment: With what I wrote, I imagined that your default devise behavior is to redirect to a given URL, which I randomly called `some_default_url`. Isn't it what you want ? if no, please explain precisely (you could edit your original post) what you want to achieve

Comment: @pjam strange, I wasn't notified of your comment. Sorry for the late response. So I updated my question. Basically, if I click on a link on my website, `/dashboard`. And `DashboardController` has `before_filter :authenticate_user!` at the top. Then I'll be redirected to a login page. Once I login, I should then be redirected on to `/dashboard` like I originally requested. That behavior needs to be maintained unless a login has a `target` parameter.

Comment: @at. Ok I think I understand the difference, I'm updating the answer

Comment: I ended up simply calling `super` if the target was not specified.