# Devise Error on editing profile with sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, devise

I am working on an application that has several areas which require user to be logged in to access. (I am using devise for logic).

I am currently using the following in my application controller to remember the target url (the link someone clicks on (that requires authentication)) such that it will take the user there after authenticating (as per [How to direct user to a specific page after logging in with Devise and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129254/how-to-direct-user-to-a-specific-page-after-logging-in-with-devise-and-rails)) .

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :content
  protect_from_forgery


  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    origin_path = session[:origin_path]
    default_redirect_path ="/"
    clear_origin_path
    if origin_path.present?
      origin_path
    else
      params[:target].presence || default_redirect_path
    end
  end

  private

  def authenticate_user!
    store_origin_path
    super
  end

    def store_session
    store_origin_path

  end

  def store_origin_path
    session[:origin_path] = request.fullpath
  end

  def clear_origin_path
    session[:origin_path] = nil
  end


end
```

This all works great, but I have just noticed that when I try to access "/users/edit", I am now given the error:

```
ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#edit

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
Rails.root: /home/james/*******

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19:in `authenticate_user!'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

_csrf_token: "XmrTSQOQ3Z0XTSn14LAX8LtMNVOwM4q3bQ+UhxjvgGM="
session_id: "2caaccc944774f2a7ac6f440c2f442d9"
user_return_to: "/my_tendersave"
warden.user.user.key: ["User", [1], "$2a$10$foTK/Em72/E0rILIuUv7su"]
warden.user.user.session: {"last_request_at"=>2013-01-25 01:48:43 UTC}
Show env dump

GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET: "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip,deflate,sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
Response

Headers:

None
```

What can I do to ensure this works?

Do I need to change the application Controller?

Or override some other devise methods.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply renamed the method in application controller and called the correct superclass method.

ie.

```
  def authenticated_user!
    store_origin_path
    authenticate_user!
  end
```